# Creating events from Google Sheets to Google Calendar - still having an issue with duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script, duplicates, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I've been trying to work this out my myself for a few weeks, but I'm at a loss! I've had some great help with modifying this script that I took from another answer, but it's still creating duplicates.

Does anyone have any ideas that would help me? Is it something obvious that I'm missing?

Current script:

```
/**
 * Adds a custom menu to the active spreadsheet, containing a single menu item
 * for invoking the exportEvents() function.
 * The onOpen() function, when defined, is automatically invoked whenever the
 * spreadsheet is opened.
 * For more information on using the Spreadsheet API, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet
 */
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Export WHCs",
    functionName : "exportWHCs"
  },
                {
    name : "Export Docs",
    functionName : "exportDocs"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Calendar Actions", entries);
};

/**
 * Export events from spreadsheet to calendar
 */
function exportWHCs() {
  // check if the script runs for the first time or not,
  // if so, create the trigger and PropertiesService.getScriptProperties() the script will use
  // a start index and a total counter for processed items
  // else continue the task
  if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getKeys().length==0){ 
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties({'itemsprocessed':0});
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('exportWHCs').timeBased().everyMinutes(5).create();
  }
  // initialize all variables when we start a new task, "notFinished" is the main loop condition
  var itemsProcessed = Number(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('itemsprocessed'));
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows = 4;  // Number of rows of header info (to skip)
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var calId = "pma5g2rd5cft4lird345j7pke8@group.calendar.google.com";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  for (i in data) {
    if (i < headerRows) continue; // Skip header row(s)
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date(row[12]);  // First column
    var title = row[18];           // Second column
    var tstart = new Date(row[15]);
    tstart.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstart.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstart.setYear(date.getYear());
    var tstop = new Date(row[16]);
    tstop.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstop.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstop.setYear(date.getYear());
    var id = row[17];              // Sixth column == eventId


    // Check if event already exists, delete it if it does
try {
  var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
  event.deleteEventSeries();
  row[17] = '';  // Remove event ID    
    }
catch (e) {
  // do nothing - we just want to avoid the exception when event doesn't exist
}
//cal.createEvent(title, new Date("March 3, 2010 08:00:00"), new Date("March 3, 2010 09:00:00"));
      var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop).addEmailReminder(5).getId();
row[17] = newEvent;  // Update the data array with event ID


    if(new Date().getTime()-startTime > 240000){ // if > 4 minutes
      var processed = i+1;// save usefull variable
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties({'itemsprocessed':processed});
      range.setValues(data);
      return;
    }    
    debugger;
  }
  // Record all event IDs to spreadsheet
  range.setValues(data);
}




/**
 * Export events from spreadsheet to calendar
 */
function exportDocs() {
  // check if the script runs for the first time or not,
  // if so, create the trigger and PropertiesService.getScriptProperties() the script will use
  // a start index and a total counter for processed items
  // else continue the task
  if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getKeys().length==0){ 
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties({'itemsprocessed':0});
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('exportDocs').timeBased().everyMinutes(5).create();
  }
  // initialize all variables when we start a new task, "notFinished" is the main loop condition
  var itemsProcessed = Number(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('itemsprocessed'));
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows = 4;  // Number of rows of header info (to skip)
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var calId = "pma5g2rd5cft4lird345j7pke8@group.calendar.google.com";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  for (i in data) {
    if (i < headerRows) continue; // Skip header row(s)
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date(row[13]);  // First column
    var title = row[19];           // Second column
    var tstart = new Date(row[15]);
    tstart.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstart.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstart.setYear(date.getYear());
    var tstop = new Date(row[16]);
    tstop.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstop.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstop.setYear(date.getYear());
    var id = row[20];              // Sixth column == eventId

    // Check if event already exists, delete it if it does
try {
  var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
  event.deleteEventSeries();
  row[20] = '';  // Remove event ID    
}
catch (e) {
  // do nothing - we just want to avoid the exception when event doesn't exist
}
//cal.createEvent(title, new Date("March 3, 2010 08:00:00"), new Date("March 3, 2010 09:00:00"));
      var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop).addEmailReminder(5).getId();
row[20] = newEvent;  // Update the data array with event ID


    if(new Date().getTime()-startTime > 240000){ // if > 4 minutes
      var processed = i+1;// save usefull variable
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties({'itemsprocessed':processed});
      range.setValues(data);
      return;
    }    
    debugger;
  }
  // Record all event IDs to spreadsheet
  range.setValues(data);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did tried to reproduce your issue. I am able to create a new event without duplicating the event. I did tried with below code.

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Export WHCs",
    functionName : "exportWHCs"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Calendar Actions", entries);
};

/**
 * Export events from spreadsheet to calendar
 */
function exportWHCs() {

  if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getKeys().length==0){ 
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties({'itemsprocessed':0});
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('exportWHCs').timeBased().everyMinutes(5).create();
  }
  // initialize all variables when we start a new task, "notFinished" is the main loop condition
  var itemsProcessed = Number(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('itemsprocessed'));
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows = 4;  // Number of rows of header info (to skip)
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var calId = "rkarumuri@google.com";
  Logger.log(calId);
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  for (i in data) {
    if (i <  headerRows) continue; // Skip header row(s)
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date(row[12]);  
    var title = row[18];           
    var tstart = new Date(row[15]);
    tstart.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstart.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstart.setYear(date.getYear());
    var tstop = new Date(row[16]);
    tstop.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstop.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstop.setYear(date.getYear());
    var id = row[17];              // Sixth column == eventId


    // Check if event already exists, delete it if it does
try {
  var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
  event.deleteEventSeries();
  row[17] = '';  // Remove event ID    
    }
catch (e) {
  // do nothing - we just want to avoid the exception when event doesn't exist
}
        var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop).addEmailReminder(5).getId();
row[17] = newEvent;  // Update the data array with event ID


    if(new Date().getTime()-startTime > 240000){ // if > 4 minutes
      var processed = i+1;// save usefull variable
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties({'itemsprocessed':processed});
      range.setValues(data);
      return;
    }    
   }
  // Record all event IDs to spreadsheet
  range.setValues(data);
}
```

Also check the points mentioned in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEventSeriesById(String)) about accessing the events form a default calendar.

I didn't get the point of deleting an existing event and adding a new event for the same values.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My calendar is not the default calendar on that account... could that be the issue?